# Android WebView inside SwipeRefreshLayout while scroll web page inner scroll SwipeRefreshLayout get invoked instead of scroll up the web page

Tags: android, webview

**I've seen some question on same issue but not any question has a working answer.**

I have faces this issue while I scroll down the web page inner scroll and when try to scroll up then the SwipeRefreshLayout widget get appeared and start refreshing the web page instead of scroll up the page.
I'm sharing a video link below as well of the issue for a visual information of the issue. https://go.screenpal.com/watch/cZeX1IV7clU.

I found a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Telefonica/android-nested-scroll-webview) in which the above issue got fixed, but  by using that repo I encounter with a new issue in which when I zoom-in the web page and scroll it towards right  it always get self scrolled towards initial left(start) position.

So I want a solution in which the inner scroll behavior and zoom behavior both issue get fixed either from some native approach or by apply some changes in the github repo.

This is concern of many as there is many questions already addressing the same issue but none of got any working solutions.

Thank you!